# Maximum angle between vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

Consider 3 vectors $\textbf{v},\textbf{v}',\textbf{u}$ related by

$$\textbf{v}=\textbf{u}+\textbf{v}'$$

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{u}$ and let $\phi$ be the angle between $\textbf{v}$ and $-\textbf{v}'$.

For what angle $\theta$ is the angle $\phi$ a maximum? The magnitudes $v,u$ are given and you can express the angle in terms of them.

I started by doing the dot product of the equation with itself getting

$$v^{2}=vu\cos\theta+vv'\cos\phi=u^{2}+v^{'2}+2uv'\cos (\pi/2-\phi-\theta)$$

I thought I would then find the derivative of this expression with respect to $\theta$ and set $d\phi/d\theta=0$. That gives

$$-vu\sin\theta=2uv'\sin(\pi/2-\phi-\theta)$$ or

$$v\sin\theta=2v'\sin(\phi+\theta-\pi/2)=-2v'\cos(\phi+\theta)$$

which seems overdetermined.

Comment: Lenghts are given?

Comment: On geometric grounds, if $|u|<|v'|$, then $\theta$ should be $0$ or $\pi$ such that $v$ and $v'$ are opposite ...

Comment: If _all three_ magnitudes are given, then both $\theta$ and $\phi$ can be computed by standard triangle solving. There's no choice and no maxima or minima.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Only v,u are given (not v'). I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're working under peculiar constraints, doing this algebraically is almost certainly a tactical error. Instead, draw a diagram:

```
      A
     / \
   u/   \v
  |/     \|
  B------>C
      v'
```

The angles are $\phi$ at C and $\theta$ at A.

$\phi$ will certainly be a maximum if we can make it $\pi$ which happens if $|u|>|v|$ and $\theta=0$.

Then consider the case $|u|<|v|$. If we have already decided on the positions of A and C, the possible positions of B is a circle with center A. Among those, the ones that maximize the angle at C are the ones where BC is tangent to the circle -- which are the ones where the angle is B is right!

Basic trigonometry then gives us $|u|=|v|\cos\theta$.

Comment: "Among those, the ones that maximize the angle at C are the ones where BC is tangent to the circle". Why is that?

Comment: @user35202: Geometrically, the tangent to the circle through C separates the rays that intersect the circle (which are the ones that represent possible $\phi$s) from those that don't intersect the circle (and therefor cannot be possible $\phi$s).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\vec v = \vec u -(-\vec v') = \vec v = \vec u -\vec w
$$

so now

$$
\vec u\cdot\vec v = ||\vec u||^2-\vec u\cdot\vec w
$$

or

$$
||\vec u||||\vec v||\cos\theta=||\vec u|| - ||\vec u||||\vec w||\cos\phi
$$

and then assuming that $\vec u\cdot\vec w \ne 0$

$$
\phi = \arccos\left(a+b\cos\theta\right)
$$

and now deriving

$$
\frac{d\phi}{d\theta} = \frac{b \sin (\theta )}{\sqrt{1-(a+b \cos (\theta ))^2}} = 0
$$

which gives $\theta = 0 + k\pi$